# Is there a concept in Julia like C++'s typedef

Tags: julia, typedef, equivalent

I'm trying to learn julia and started by rewriting one of my C++ programs.

I'm having problems in finding a good way of representing the following concept in Julia.

I have a few structs all of which are some sort of collection. Let's say I have an AddressBook and a PhotoAlbum. Each collection has very different elements. Now, in C++ it's quite easy to create a variable of type Photo if I know that a PhotoAlbum was passed into a function.

I can't quite think of a equivalent way in julia. Ideally, the compiler should know exactly which type the collection consists of so it can optimise as much as possible.

This is how I would do it in C++

```c
class AddressBook
{
  public:
    typedef PersonalDetail Element;
}


class PhotoAlbum
{
  public:
    typedef Photo Element;
}


template<typename Collection>
void printFirstElement<Collection>(const Collection& c)
{
  const typename Collection::Element firstElement = //c.first();...
  // do something with firstElement
}
```

Comment: I have posted my try at preliminary answer to your question. However, if you present a more complete example of the design problem you want to solve yet a different pattern might be recommended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly I would say that you do not have to think about it, because the compiler will know the required types. For example in your code above when you would call `first(c)` (this would be an equivalent of `c.first()`) the type of this variable will be known at compile time (you can confirm this by running `@code_warntype` on your function).

If you would provide a complete small working example I could give you a working code for this.

A more advanced topic is attaching some metadata to your types. There are several ways you could do it. Let me show you one of them - via a parametric abstract type.

```
abstract type AbstractCollection{T} end
struct PersonalDetail end
struct AddressBook <: AbstractCollection{PersonalDetail} end
struct Photo end
struct PhotoAlbum <: AbstractCollection{Photo} end
getcollectiontype(::AbstractCollection{T}) where T = T
```

and now you can write something like this to extract the metadata

```
julia> ab = AddressBook()
AddressBook()

julia> pa = PhotoAlbum()
PhotoAlbum()

julia> getcollectiontype(ab)
PersonalDetail

julia> getcollectiontype(pa)
Photo
```

Of course it is a MWE, and I am not sure if you need it in your code (if you show a small full working code we can discuss the best implementation strategy).

Also something like this might be not needed at all. For example you have a standard function `eltype` that is expected to return a type of element in a collection. For this function you could add methods for your specific types to get the information about element type they hold. Then you can simply run `eltype(collection)` in your code and again - at compile time - you will have the information about element type of the collection.

Also note that types in Julia as also values so for example the following code just works and compiler knows all types as need (the function `f` tries to convert its second argument `y` to the type of its first argument `x` using the type constructor):

```
julia> f(x,y) = typeof(x)(y)
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f(10, 2.0)
2

julia> f(10.0, 2)
2.0

julia> @code_warntype f(10.0, 2)
Body::Float64
1 ─ %1 = (Base.sitofp)(Float64, y)::Float64
└──      return %1
```

The definition above is equivalent to the following one `f(x::T,y) = T(y)`.

Answer (score -2):

Since variables in Julia can hold types, you can just do

```
struct PersonalDetail
end
struct Photo
end

struct AddressBook
    Element
    AddressBook(Element=PersonalDetail) = new(Element)
end

struct PhotoAlbum
    Element
    PhotoAlbum(Element=Photo) = new(Element)
end

PhotoAlbum()
```

That being said, you can write functions without specifying their types

```
function printFirstElement(c)
    @show c[1]
end
printFirstElement([AddressBook()])
printFirstElement([PhotoAlbum()])
printFirstElement([rand([AddressBook() PhotoAlbum()])])
printFirstElement(1:5) # doesn't specify element type with `Element`, but we can still access its first element
```

Comment: This isn't valid Julia code and, semantically, will have bad performance as the fields in the structs aren't concretely typed.